# Nothing to be done for 'all'

Tags: makefile

Im trying to run this simple makefile commands but get the error - 'Nothing to be done for 'all''

```
FILES = file1.c file2.c file3.c
all:test

test:
    for file in $(FILES);
        do
            echo $$file;
        done
```

Comment: You have a file or directory named `test`. Also, it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target `test` has no dependencies and therefore no reason to be built, which is inherited by the target `all`. It has instructions, but it should include `FILES` as its prerequisites. What you're doing appears to be ingredients-first, but `test` is the target. Working backwards is what `make` is best at. You may benefit from an article called "[Auto-Dependency Generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/)" which takes the opposite approach (you appear to think like I do.)

`test: $(FILES)`

Then you could do something like the following:

`$(FILES:.o:.c): %.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<`

The first part is a set of possible targets, the list of objects corresponding to the list of sources, and the second is a specific but nameless object (it will assume the name of the corresponding source.) Later on, the target, e.g. `test`, can be the name of your executable taking these objects as both dependencies and objects to link statically. For my purposes I typically use shared libraries but this is irrelevant to the question at hand.

Edit: untested, will revise if issues ensue